# VBA - You cant paste this here because the copy area and paste area aren't the same size

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy rows based on the below if criteria from one sheet to another. I want the copied data to be pasted in cell H4. When i do that i get the following message: You cant paste this here because the copy area and paste area aren't the same size.

So the problem is the size of the copy and pasting region but i cant seem to figure out how to solve this.

```
        Lastrow = Sheets("Data").range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 2 To Lastrow
            
            If Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "D").Value = "US" Then
                Sheets("Data").Cells(i, "D").EntireRow.Copy 
                 Destination:=Sheets("Main").range("H4")

            End If
        Next i
```

Comment: You can't paste an *entire* row starting in column H. It won't fit. Better to find the last column first, before copying. Note that you can use `Range.AutoFilter` here instead of looping, which is inefficient.

Comment: Thank you Ben - I solved it using autofilter - much easier compared to for loops.